# How to re-save a referenced entity that is removed when saving the referencing entity?

Tags: entities, 9

I have added a field to the **Tags** vocabulary, **Count**.

In my **Tags** taxonomy term entity bundle, I run a database query in `preSave()` to set the value of this field (how many nodes have an entity reference to this term).

To keep the **Tags** term counts up to date, when a node with a **Tags** entity reference field is saved, in `postSave()` on my node bundle, I resave the **Tags** term:

```
  public function postSave(EntityStorageInterface $storage, $update = TRUE): int {
    $tag_id = (int) $this->field_tags->target_id;
    if ($tag_id > 0) {
      $term = $this->entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($tag_id);
      $term->save();
    }
    parent::postSave($storage, $update);
    return 1;
  }
```

This is fine when adding tags.

However, when removing tags, then the term for the removed tag is not resaved, so the count is incorrect.

I tried to fix this in the node entity bundle's `preSave()`:

```
if (!$this->isNew()) {
  $tag_id = (int) $this->field_tags->target_id;
  $original_node = $this->original;
  $original_tag_id = (int) $original_node->field_tags->target_id;
    // If ID of group has changed or been removed, we also need to resave the original.
    if ($original_tag_id > 0 && ($original_tag_id !== $tag_id)) {
      $term = $this->entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($original_tag_id);
      $term->save();
    }
  }
}
```

While this code re-saves the term that is resaved, because this is run in `preSave()`, it runs before the node is updated, so the count is off by one because the node has not been updated (to remove the tag) yet.

So I'm stuck-- to get the `original` node to detect if a tag is removed, I need to be in `preSave`, but to resave the tag, I need to do so in `postSave`.

Is there some way I can trigger a re-save of an entity after editing another entity, but only after the edited entity has been saved?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have access to $this->original in postSave()?

Comment: @4uk4 Yes, when I try the `preSave()` code above in `postSave()`, I get `Warning: Attempt to read property "field_tags" on null in Drupal\MyModule\Bundle\NodeBundle->postSave()` .

Comment: The problem could be the condition isNew() because when a new entity is saved it is no longer new, but $this->original should work, if it s not a new entity, just tested it in my IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `postSave` event you can no longer test `isNew()`. So check for the original entity instead, which is only present if the save operation is updating and not creating an entity:

```
if (isset($this->original)) {
  $original_node = $this->original;
```